# Flutter global Providers

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im Junior at flutter

I have a project that I use `Provider` for state management,

In my app I have `App Provider` That I use it in all other provide classes and It's hold datas for use them in all the project.

My Application `main class` is here,and its too dirty:)

i implemented this class like this :

```
final ThemeData androidTheme =
    ThemeData(fontFamily: 'ChiscoText', dividerColor: Colors.transparent);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  AppController appController = AppController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const defaultTextStyle =
        TextStyle(fontFamily: 'ChiscoText', color: Styles.primaryTextColor);

    return Sizer(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation,
          DeviceType deviceType) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: appController,
            child: Consumer<AppController>(
                builder: (context, AppController controller, child) =>
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      },
                      child: MaterialApp(
                        theme: androidTheme,
                        title: 'Chisco',
                        routes: {
                          loginPage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                child: const AuthScreen(),
                                create: (ctx) => AuthController(context),
                              ),
                          splashPage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (context) => SplashController(context),
                                child: const SplashScreen(),
                              ),
                          homePage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (context) => HomeController(context),
                                child: const Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                    child: HomeScreen()),
                              ),
                          accountPage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (context) => AccountController(context),
                                child: const Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                    child: AccountScreen()),
                              ),
                          profilePage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (context) => ProfileController(context),
                                child: const Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                    child: ProfileScreen()),
                              ),
                          coolerDevicePage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    CoolerController(context),
                                child: const Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                    child: CoolerScreen()),
                              ),
                          schedulePage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    ScheduleController(context),
                                child: const Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                    child: ScheduleScreen()),
                              ),
                          powerDevicePage: (context) => const Directionality(
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              child: PowerScreen()),
                          testPage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (context) => HomeController(context),
                                child: const Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                    child: TestScreen()),
                              ),
                        },
                        initialRoute: splashPage,
                      ),
                    )));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here Im using `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` for create `AppController` instance in all project.

Now I want use one more provider class like `AppController` that I use it in all other providers (Common provider class).

its for connecting to mqtt,

do i have use `MultiProvider` inseted of `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` for creating `AppController` and `mqttController`??

and what is your suggestion for make my code simpler and cleaner??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create `route.dart` file and put all your route in it like this:

```
var routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  '/loginPage': (context) => AuthScreen(),
  ...
};
```

then:

```
 Sizer(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation,
          DeviceType deviceType) {
        return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider<AppController>(create: (_) => AppController()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<AppControllerTwo>(create: (_) => AppControllerTwo()),
            ],
            child: Consumer2(
                builder: (context,AppControllerTwo controllerTwo, AppController controller, child) =>
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      },
                      child: MaterialApp(
                        theme: androidTheme,
                        title: 'Chisco',
                        routes: routes,
                        initialRoute: splashPage,
                      ),
                    )));
      },
    )
```

you can call `Consumer2`, `Consumer3`, `Consumer4`,`Consumer5` and`Consumer6`.

and when ever you need your controller value use this:

```
AppController controller = Provider.of<AppController>(context, listen: false);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but how can i use two global provider class? `AppController` and `MqttController`

Comment: I updated my answer two handle MultiProvider.

Comment: what usage of consumer2 , 3 , 4, 5 ,and others?

Comment: if you have two global providers use consumer2, if you have three global providers use consumer3 etc.

Comment: `loginPage: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
 child: const AuthScreen(), create: (ctx) => AuthController(context),),` Sorry But in ur code u didnt pass Sreeens Controllers To Routes,

Comment: what is Screens Controller?

Comment: Its a provider Class for my Screens and every screen has their own Controller                 for `AuthController` is Provider class for `AuthScreen`

Comment: I think it is better uses this provider in their own class. For example like main.dart , use ChangeNotifierProvider at the top of AuthScreen and pass AuthController to it. It is not clean when you pass AuthController when you are  define AuthScreen route.